# Python - Degrees of freedom

Tags: python, math

I am trying to calculate degrees of freedom and I've used following formula:

[image: formula[1]]

Unfortunately, it gives me the wrong answer.

My code:

```
def stdev(X):
    m = mean(X)
    return math.sqrt(sum((x-m)**2 for x in X) / len(X))

def degreesOfFreedom(X, Y):
    s1 = (stdev(X)**2)
    s2 = (stdev(Y)**2)
    df = (s1 / len(X) + s2 / len(Y))**2 / ((s1 / len(X))**2 / (len(X) - 1) + (s2 / len(Y))**2 / len(Y) - 1)
    return(df)

print('Degrees of freedom for Student-t distribution: ' + str(degreesOfFreedom(A, B)))
```

Where A and B are independent arrays containing numerical values.
Instead of obtaining a valuable values, I see a result in the form:

> Degrees of freedom for Student-t distribution: -0.00004981053615260864

Comment: Missing parenthesis around `len(Y) - 1`

Comment: FYI, there's a `stdev` function if you use python 3.6: https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.stdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 len(Y))**2 / len(Y) - 1)
```

Due to missing parenthesis around

```
  len(y) - 1
```

According to BODMAS, the division takes place first, thus the wrong error